# Assign a user role based on radio button check Ultimate Member

Tags: wordpress, registration, ultimate-member

I'm using Ultimate Member for my registration process and I've added a custom radio button to check if the user is a Contractor or not.
As default it would assign "Customer" role to new users, but I want it to assign the role "Contractor" when that radio button is checked.
I tried to go through Ultimate Member settings, nothing helped me, the only available rules in the registration form for the radio button are show and hide, there's nothing related to which role to assign !
Hope you can help me, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create the rol from UM->Profile->Add New Role.
You sholud create as many profiles you need.
After that, on Register form, you should add the "profile Radio Button".
The button configuration will show all roles your wordpress have. You should mantain those you want and delete from options which you don't
PD: BE CAREFULL... You can't change role names. If you do, the registration form will not show them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).